# QSystemTrayIcon doesn't work at another computer

Tags: c++, qt, qsystemtrayicon

I have a problem with `QSystemTrayIcon`. I've built the application on two different computers. I've built in the first computer and launch the application on the another and vice versa.
The problem is that I don't see any icon in the tray menu, but the process is running (if I launch the application on the computer on which it was built, everything works fine). **I've googled a lot and stuck with this issue**.

Icon located near the executable file. Also, I have the folder `imageformats` with `qico.dll` but nothing changed.

```
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.addLibraryPath(app.applicationDirPath());

    auto trayIcon = std::make_shared<QSystemTrayIcon>(":/icon.ico");
    Handler handler(trayIcon);

    trayIcon->setVisible(true);
    trayIcon->setToolTip("tooltip");
```

Answer (score 0):

Soooo, the problem was in the .ico format of the application image. When I changed it to the icon with the .png extension, it works fine.